# How do I use the dataset annotated on Makesense.ai to train a deep learning model? The annotations generated is present in a single .json file

Tags: json, deep-learning, annotations, image-segmentation

Could anyone help me out on this please.
This is for Image Segmentaion.
I tried searching about this but I only found posts talking about independant .json annotations for each image.